# How many set partitions of [n] are there in which 1 is not in a block of size 1?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I'm not at all sure how to solve the following question:
How many set partitions of [n] are there in which 1 is not in a block of size 1?
Could someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: what does block size mean? Please be specific and also show your try

Comment: Block refers to one of the partitions and the block of size 1 means how many numbers have been "put" in that specific set partition.

Comment: I still didn't get you, can you give me an example?

Comment: This is what a set partition is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20partition%20of,partition%20defines%20an%20equivalence%20relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I understood ,

If $n = \{1,2,3\}$

Then the partitions of n are,

$P_1 = \{ \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\} \}$

$P_2 = \{ \{1, 2\}, \{3\} \}$

$P_3 = \{ \{1, 3\}, \{2\} \}$

$P_4 = \{ \{1\}, \{2, 3\} \}$

$P_5 = \{ \{1, 2, 3\} \}$

But according to your question we cannot consider $P_1$ and $P_4$ as $1$ is inside a block of size $1$.

So what we can do is , remove $1$ from the set and then calculate the number of partitions of the new set .

$n' = \{2,3\}$

Then the partitions of $n'$ are,

$P'_1 = \{  \{2\}, \{3\} \}$

$P'_2 = \{ \{2, 3\}\}$

Now to these partitions we can plug in $\{1\}$ , and get all the partitions which have $\{1\}$ in a block of size $1$, i.e $P_1$ and $P_4$.

So the number of partitions which do not have $1$ in a block size of $1 = B_n - B_{n-1}$
where $B_n$ is the Bell number.